# Python multiprocessing Pool.apply_async with shared variables (Value)

Tags: python, linux, pool, python-multiprocessing

For my college project I am trying to develop a python based traffic generator.I have created 2 CentOS machines on vmware and I am using 1 as my client and 1 as my server machine. I have used [IP aliasing](http://www.tecmint.com/create-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-single-network-interface/) technique to increase number of clients and severs using just single client/server machine. Upto now I have created 50 IP alias on my client machine and 10 IP alias on my server machine. I am also using multiprocessing module to generate traffic concurrently from all 50 clients to all 10 servers. I have also developed few profiles(1kb,10kb,50kb,100kb,500kb,1mb) on my server(in /var/www/html directory since I am using Apache Server) and I am using urllib2 to send request to these profiles from my client machine. I am using [httplib+urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903520/how-to-send-http-request-using-virtual-ip-address-in-linux) to first bind to any one of the source alias ip and then send request from this ip using urllib2. Here to [increase my number of TCP Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296557/create-new-tcp-connections-for-every-http-request-in-python/29296806?noredirect=1#comment46808522_29296806), I am trying to use multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async module. But I am getting this error 'RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance' while running my scripts. After a bit of debugging I found that this error is caused due to use of multiprocessing.Value. But I want to share some variables between my processes and I also want to increase my number of TCP Connections. What other module(other than multiprocessing.Value) can be used here to share some common variables? Or else is there any other solution for this query?

```
'''
Traffic Generator Script:

 Here I have used IP Aliasing to create multiple clients on single vm machine. 
 Same I have done on server side to create multiple servers. I have around 50 clients and 10 servers
'''
import multiprocessing
import urllib2
import random
import myurllist    #list of all destination urls for all 10 servers
import time
import socbindtry   #script that binds various virtual/aliased client ips to the script
m=multiprocessing.Manager()
response_time=m.list()    #some shared variables
error_count=multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
def send_request3():    #function to send requests from alias client ip 1
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler3)    #bind to alias client ip1
    try:
        tstart=time.time()
        for i in range(myurllist.url):
            x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
            opener.open(x).read()
            print "file downloaded:",x
            response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error_count.value=error_count.value+1
def send_request4():    #function to send requests from alias client ip 2
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler4)    #bind to alias client ip2
    try:
        tstart=time.time()
        for i in range(myurllist.url):
            x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
            opener.open(x).read()
            print "file downloaded:",x
            response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error_count.value=error_count.value+1
#50 such functions are defined here for 50 clients
def func():
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=750)
    for i in range(5):
        pool.apply_async(send_request3)
        pool.apply_async(send_request4)
        pool.apply_async(send_request5)
#append 50 functions here
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print"All work Done..!!"
    return
start=float(time.time())
func()
end=float(time.time())-start
print end
```

Comment: `response_time` , is your shared variable, isn't it?

Comment: Use, `multiprocessing.Queue`, instead of one global variable, IMO.

Comment: Pool.apply_async works perfectly if I dont use shared variables response_time and error_count.

Comment: @pnv yes response_time and error_count are my shared variables.

Comment: @pnv I have never worked with multiprocessing.Queue. can you guide me how do I use multiprocessing.Queue here?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's the solution, but you can try it. 
http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html

Comment: Well, I forgot that you have used `m.list`, it should not throw any error. Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: yes i think it is because of using Value module for error_count (and few more variables that I have not mentioned here).

Comment: yes m.list is not throwing any error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74409/discussion-between-pnv-and-bhoomika-sheth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error messages states, you can't pass a `multiprocessing.Value` via pickle. However, you can use a [`multiprocessing.Manager().Value`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Value):

```
import multiprocessing
import urllib2
import random
import myurllist    #list of all destination urls for all 10 servers
import time
import socbindtry   #script that binds various virtual/aliased client ips to the script

def send_request3(response_time, error_count):    #function to send requests from alias client ip 1
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler3)    #bind to alias client ip1
    try:
        tstart=time.time()
        for i in range(myurllist.url):
            x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
            opener.open(x).read()
            print "file downloaded:",x
            response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        with error_count.get_lock():
            error_count.value += 1

def send_request4(response_time, error_count):    #function to send requests from alias client ip 2
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler4)    #bind to alias client ip2
    try:
        tstart=time.time()
        for i in range(myurllist.url):
            x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
            opener.open(x).read()
            print "file downloaded:",x
            response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        with error_count.get_lock():
            error_count.value += 1

#50 such functions are defined here for 50 clients

def func(response_time, error_count):
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2*multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    args = (response_time, error_count)
    for i in range(5):
        pool.apply_async(send_request3, args=args)
        pool.apply_async(send_request4, args=args)
#append 50 functions here
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print"All work Done..!!"
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m=multiprocessing.Manager()
    response_time=m.list()    #some shared variables
    error_count=m.Value('i',0)

    start=float(time.time())
    func(response_time, error_count)
    end=float(time.time())-start
    print end
```

A few other notes here:

1. Using a `Pool` with 750 processes is not a good idea. Unless you're using a server with hundreds of CPU cores, that's going to overwhelm your machine. It'd be faster and put less strain on your machine to use significantly fewer processes. Something more like `2 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.
2. As a best practice, you should explicitly pass all the shared arguments you need to use to the child processes, rather than using global variables. This increases the chances that the code will be work on Windows.
3. It looks like all your `send_request*` functions do almost the exact same thing. Why not just make one function and use a variable to decide which `socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler` to use? You would avoid a *ton* of code duplication by doing this.
4. The way you're incrementing `error_count` is not process/thread-safe, and is susceptible to race conditions. You need to protect the increment with a lock (as I did in the example code above).

Comment: @dano, do you need the lock on a manager managed Value? Doesn't the manager take care of access to the the Value? Also see https://bugs.python.org/issue35786

Comment: @Avraham Yes, I believe you do. The manager-managed Value is just a proxy to a regular Value, so I don't think there's any way it could make the `+=` operation atomic, since it would result in two separate calls to the proxy (once to get the current value, and then another to set the it to the new val). Good catch on the `get_lock()` issue. I think you'd have to use a manager-managed `Lock()` instead.

Comment: @dano, FWIW, in code I'm using, passing a manager value to a pool called asynchronoulsy on 15 files, using plain managed values work just fine without using a manager lock but fail to perform when preceded by a with lock. I was investigating if value would be faster than the queue I was using as a counter, and the answer seems to be no, as you said, since I'm using a Pool, everyting gets pickled and the manager handles access to the queue and value both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, because 
[Python Multiprocess diff between Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596617/python-multiprocess-diff-between-windows-and-linux)
(I seriously, don't know how multiprocessing works in VMs, as is the case here.)

This might work;

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import myurllist    #list of all destination urls for all 10 servers
import time

def send_request3(response_time, error_count):    #function to send requests from alias client ip 1
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler3)    #bind to alias client ip1
    try:
        tstart=time.time()
        for i in range(myurllist.url):
            x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
            opener.open(x).read()
            print "file downloaded:",x
            response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error_count.value=error_count.value+1
def send_request4(response_time, error_count):    #function to send requests from alias client ip 2
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler4)    #bind to alias client ip2
    try:
        tstart=time.time()
        for i in range(myurllist.url):
            x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
            opener.open(x).read()
            print "file downloaded:",x
            response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        error_count.value=error_count.value+1
#50 such functions are defined here for 50 clients
def func():
    m=multiprocessing.Manager()
    response_time=m.list()    #some shared variables
    error_count=multiprocessing.Value('i',0)

    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=750)
    for i in range(5):
        pool.apply_async(send_request3, [response_time, error_count])
        pool.apply_async(send_request4, [response_time, error_count])
        # pool.apply_async(send_request5)
#append 50 functions here
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print"All work Done..!!"
    return


start=float(time.time())
func()
end=float(time.time())-start
print end
```

Comment: No this didnt work for me.. anyways thanks for helping

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in VM, all the matters is the OS running inside the VM. That's the whole point of VMs - none of the software running inside it needs to know that it's not real hardware. The VMs are running CentOS, so all the normal Linux `multiprocessing` behaviors apply.